# Directions Service of Google Maps API doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Do you have any idea why my directions service of Google Maps API doesn't work? It seems that method directionsService.route() isn't executed (cause alert with status is not displayed), but I don't know why. I'm newbie in Google Maps API and JS, so try to be forgiving, if it's something simple. :)

```
var map = null;
var pos = null;
const STORED_LOC = new google.maps.LatLng(50.405196, 11.894855);
var currentLat = document.getElementById("latLabel");
var currentLng = document.getElementById("lngLabel");
var additionalInfo = document.getElementById("additionalInfo");

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize()
{
    pos = STORED_LOC;
    currentLat.innerHTML = pos.lat();
    currentLng.innerHTML = pos.lng();

    options =
        {
            center: pos,
            zoom: 15
        }

    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title: "Chosen localization"
        }
    );

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), options);
    marker.setMap(map);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

$("#yes").click(function () {
    getPosition();
    hideUserConsentSection();
});

$("#no").click(function () {
    hideUserConsentSection();
    showSetCustomLocationSection();
});

function showSetCustomLocationSection() {
    $("#setCustomLocationSection").show();
}

function hideUserConsentSection() {
    $("#userConsentSection").hide();
}

function getPosition() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 2000
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorPosition, options);
    }

    else
    {
        additionalInfo.innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support geolocation";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    currentLat.innerHTML = pos.lat();
    currentLng.innerHTML = pos.lng();

    var request =
        {
            origin: STORED_LOC,
            destination: pos,
            travelmode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status)
    {
        alert(status);
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
            alert("OKAY");
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
    //map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), options);
    //marker.setMap(map);

}

function errorPosition(position) {
    switch (position.code) {
        case 1:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        case 2:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        case 3:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My HTML looks like that:

```
<h3>How to reach us?</h3>

<div id="userConsentSection">Can we use your geolocation?<br />
     <input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" id="no" value="No" /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="setCustomLocationSection" style="display:none">
    Enter your geolocation. <br /><br />
    <input type="text" id="customLocation" />
    <input type="button" id="setCustomLocationButton" value="Show" /><br /><br />
</div>

<span>Latitude: </span>
<div id="latLabel">
</div>

<span>Longitude: </span>
<div id="lngLabel">
</div>

<div id="additionalInfo">
</div>

<div id="mapContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&sensor=true">
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  A jsfiddle that reproduces the problem would be useful.

Comment: For a newbie you have a lot of code.Start from [**Demo**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) and  understand it. Then incrementally add features till you finish off with the product you require

Comment: @davidstrachan - the whole code is understandable for me, I wrote them, that's why I don't know what mistake I've done. Your post is not useful at all and totally unproductive. If you know what is wrong in that piece of code - please explain it.

Comment: You may want to change your title. Consider that thousands if not millions of websites use the API, successfully, the problem has a high chance of not being that the *api doesn't work*.

Comment: @geocodezip - I've added HTML. I'm still fighting with that code and now I know that route method isn't performing. Did I any lapse in field of creating directionsService object? I have to find out this answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is typo in request object - travelmode instead travelMode. This parameter is required and as the result - route method doesn't execute. Be careful with that name!